# Generate links based on the InnerHTML of the anchor to convert timezones

Tags: javascript

I have a large html list of events with different schedules that I need to convert to local time zones.  So my idea is to link all the hours to a custom duck duck search .

For now my problem is generating an individual link to each anchor, it only works for the first one . I can't assign manually an id to every link .

```
<div class="links">
<a href="javascript: null" >8 pm</a>
<a href="javascript: null" >9 am</a>
<a href="javascript: null" >10 pm</a>
<a href="javascript: null" >3 am</a>
<a href="javascript: null" >5 pm</a>
</div>

<script>
document.querySelector('.links a').addEventListener("click", function () {
    window.location.href = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q="+this.innerHTML+"+GMT+to+local+time&ia=answer";
});
</script>
```

This is my first attempt, I am a beginner with javascript but I want to do it without using jquery or other libraries.
( In the future I want to try how to make the time conversion using the duckduck go api and show it in a tooltip or modal . But first I need to solve this first step)

Thank you.

Comment: Use document.getElementsByTagName("a") to select all a tags.

Answer (score 1):

You want to attach a click event to multiple elements, you should select all the elements and add the event listener to all of them individually.

Here is a simple way to do it.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

 for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        window.location.href = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q="+this.innerHTML+"+GMT+to+local+time&ia=answer";
    });
 }
```

**Note**:

"**querySelector**" returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned, so in this case you were adding the event listener to the first a tag.

"**getElementsByTagName**" returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name, which means all elements in the page with that tag will have the listener attached.